# Login using UrlFetchApp function and scrape private data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-apps

I need to scrape private data from portal which doesn't support API. 
`IMPORTXML` can't do this because of login.

I have a link with information of from & to date and the content is table with cost data. I need to login and scrape simple table into my Google Sheet.

I need to log in into this website:

> https://www.glami.cz/registrace/prihlasit

and than scrape this url:

> https://partner.glami.cz/s/e-commerce/days/866/?from=2016-12-01&to=2016-12-09

The form on this site is:

```
<form action="/registrace/prihlasit/" method="post" id="frm-signIn">
<dl class="form">
    <dt><label for="frm-signIn-username" class="required">Emailová adresa</label></dt>
    <dd><input type="text" name="username" id="frm-signIn-username" required data-nette-rules='[{"op":":filled","msg":"Prosím, vyplňte emailovou adresu."}]' class="text"></dd>
    <dt><label for="frm-signIn-password" class="required">Heslo</label></dt>
    <dd><input type="password" name="password" id="frm-signIn-password" required data-nette-rules='[{"op":":filled","msg":"Prosím, vyplňte heslo."}]' class="text"></dd>
    <dt></dt>
    <dd><input type="submit" name="send" value="Přihlásit se" class="button"></dd>
</dl>
<div><input type="hidden" name="_do" value="signIn-submit"></div>
</form>
```

I have this code which works for other websites. In this case the response from logger is still "didnt log in".

```
function fetchAdminPage() {
   var url = "https://www.glami.cz/registrace/prihlasit";
   var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": {
        'username': 'LOGIN',
        'password': 'PASSWORD',
        'send': 'Přihlásit se',
        '_do': 'signIn-submit',
        "testcookie": 1
      },
      "followRedirects": false
   };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
   if ( response.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {
     // Incorrect user/pass combo
     Logger.log("didnt log in");
   } else if ( response.getResponseCode() == 302 ) {
     // Logged-in
     var headers = response.getAllHeaders();
     if ( typeof headers['Set-Cookie'] !== 'undefined' ) {
        // Make sure that we are working with an array of cookies
        var cookies = typeof headers['Set-Cookie'] == 'string' ? [ headers['Set-Cookie'] ] : headers['Set-Cookie'];
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
           // We only need the cookie's value - it might have path, expiry time, etc here
           cookies[i] = cookies[i].split( ';' )[0];
        };
        url = "https://partner.glami.cz/s/e-commerce/days/866/?from=2016-12-01&to=2016-12-09";
        options = {
            "method": "get",
            // Set the cookies so that we appear logged-in
            "headers": {
               "Cookie": cookies.join(';')
            }
        };
        response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
     };
     Logger.log(response.getContentText()); 
   };     
}
```

The problem has to be I guess somewhere in payload/options or in url adress. Can't figure out what's wrong and how to log in succesfully.

Comment: I've updated the code. Response code is 200. Username and password are 100 % correct.

Comment: So I tried this code for another website and it works. So the problem has to be in payload, options or in link. Still not sure where is the problem... I've double checked it multiple times.

Comment: Hi, your point remember me a snippet you can find here https://github.com/rielzzapps/gas_session never had to use it for now but may it can help you to deal with cookies