# Log in and Scrape, Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to log in to scrape data from [This Website](https://www.hanteochart.com/ranking/?type=album&term=weekly), but I cannot seem to be able to get past the log in phase yet, I copied a cope that I found on here, adjusting the user details to match my own of course. But it never seems to get past the log in stage?

This is the code I have

```
function fetchAdminPage() {
   var url = "https://www.hanteochart.com/login";
   var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": {
        'userEmail': '****',
        'userPass': '****',
        '_do': 'loginBtn',
        "testcookie": 1
      },
      "followRedirects": false
   };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
   if ( response.getResponseCode() == 302 ) {
     // Incorrect user/pass combo
     Logger.log("didnt log in");
   } else if ( response.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {
     // Logged-in
     var headers = response.getAllHeaders();
     if ( typeof headers['Set-Cookie'] !== 'undefined' ) {
        // Make sure that we are working with an array of cookies
        var cookies = typeof headers['Set-Cookie'] == 'string' ? [ headers['Set-Cookie'] ] : headers['Set-Cookie'];
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
           // We only need the cookie's value - it might have path, expiry time, etc here
           cookies[i] = cookies[i].split( ';' )[0];
        };
        url = "https://www.hanteochart.com/ranking/?type=album&term=weekly";
        options = {
            "method": "get",
            // Set the cookies so that we appear logged-in
            "headers": {
               "Cookie": cookies.join(';')
            }
        };
        response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
     };
     Logger.log(response.getContentText()); 
   };     
}
```

After running the script, I check the logs and this is all that appears
[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/RBGzsg8c)

This to me is clearly showing I am still not logged in, as the login box should not appear in the code, and the table I wish to extract, that you can only obtain when logged in, is still not here

Comment: You should include the errors/ logs you are getting when trying to log in.

Comment: In my log it simply says "didnt log in", thats all. I am using the correct username and password

Comment: Haven't tried signing up but on inspecting the elements the id for the password is userPass not userpass

Comment: I fixed that, usadly it is still not working! It's okay, i dont expect you to sign up to a random website for me! I will just have to keep trying to play with it

Comment: You code included `if ( response.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {
     // Incorrect user/pass combo
     Logger.log("didnt log in");
   }`, but usually a response code 200 means that your URL fetch request was correct! I think you have the coditions for `200` and `302` the wrong way around! Where do you have this code from?

Comment: I got it from here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060098/login-using-urlfetchapp-function-and-scrape-private-data

Comment: I changed them around, and it worked! sort of, I get back the full script of the page in my log, but it shows that I am not logged in still, I will update the OP to show the new code, and log.

Comment: Great, I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the website and there are a couple of things that look like they are tripping you up:

1) the url that you are posting to is not correct -- for future reference, you can open up the developer pane in your browser and go to the 'network' tab and you can see the posts as they come across in your browser.  This has been invaluable as I started to do more and more automation.

your code should post to :

```
var url = 'https://www.hanteochart.com/hanteoLogin';
```

2) in your script you have additional options of `_do`, and `testcookie1`.  Although I don't think this is causing an error, they aren't used in the form or POST for the website and likely could/should be omitted.

3) and most importantly, you define your options variable, however, you don't include it in the call to UrlFetchApp.  This line in your code should be:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
```

I ran this code in GAS with dummy credentials and was able to have a JSON response returned.  Can you update this and run it and let me know if these changes fix your issue?

As an alternative to working out the login script, a quick-and-dirty that I have done (successfully) a lot is to login with my browser and look at the cookies present and the store the cookie value in a secure location (i.e. ideally not in the script code itself) that can be called from your script any time you want to access a page from behind the login.  Works in most cases that I have tried it where the auth login cookie doesn't expire for a while.